# ACR User Dialogs Plugin for windows phone 8.1

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone-8.1, mvvmcross

where can i find this plugin for windows phone 8.1 apps. Am getting instance null when i use this plugin in windows phone 8.1 app.

my requirement is i am developing an app for andorid, ios, and windows phone 8.1. in android 
`UserDialogs.Instance.Toast("message")` this line is working fine. where as in windows phone 8.1 app instance is null.

can someone please advice.

Comment: may i know the reason why i got -1 for this question ?

Comment: have you ever found a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the [GitHub page](https://github.com/aritchie/acrmvvmcross) for that project you'll see Windows Phone "is in the works".  It looks like there is some WinPhone source code available [from here](https://github.com/aritchie/acrmvvmcross/tree/master/Acr.MvvmCross.Plugins.UserDialogs.WinPhone) as well, but it might not be fully tested, or it might be incomplete.  I suggest starting from there.

If all else fails you can write your own implementation of the interfaces used by this plugin, and then register your implementations with the SimpleIoC. Read the [MvvmCross plugin documentation](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/MvvmCross-plugins#how-plugins-are-loaded-) for more information.